# Symfony2 SontataAdminBundle change filter label

Tags: symfony

How to change filter label on AdminBundle? Example in [documentations](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#label) doesn't work

> ->add('tags', null, array('label' => 'les tags')

Answer (score 3):

You're changing the label used with filters. Use `configureListFields()` method instead of `configureDatagridFilters()`.

**Edit**: Also, you should use **name** instead of **label**.

```
/**
 * @param Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper $listMapper
 *
 * @return null
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('title')
        ->add('isPublished', null, array('name' => 'Is published?'))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, in the last version of Sonata, you should use **label** instead of **name**.

That seems more logic.